# Change header binding according to component

Tags: angular

In app.component.html, I have this code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/viewAll">Birthday Manager</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <span>{{ headerText }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have created service which is shared by 3 components and the service has the property "headerText".

In my app.component.ts file, I have done this:

```
headerText = this.sharedService.headerText;
```

Now, In one of my components', I have done this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.headerText = 'Create Employee';
}
```

But still, the headerText binding is not getting updated.

How to do this?

Comment: post your code for service. At first glance you are just assigning value to `headerText` rather than setting it using service method. so it wont get updated in another component

Comment: are You add Your `SharedService` into `providers` object of `AppModule`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

sharedService: any = {};

constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.headerText = 'Create Employee';
}
}
```

app.component.html

```
<span>{{sharedService.headerText}}</span>
```

Comment: @RaviTeja wow, excellent job. Could you explain me how it's work?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you mistake two ways to solve your issue... The simplest way is using reference to service in your html code:

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <span>{{ sharedService.headerText }}</span>
</div>
```

if refernce to service is public.

**But the best solution** (and I guess that you wanted use it) is using Observables object. It's a long topic (you can read about it [here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html)), but you will be able to declare variable one time in your component, and keep track of all changes on it.

**In a nutshell:** You have to declare Observable object in your service `title: Observable<string>`, and if you pass reference to observable in some component `headerTitle$: Observable<string> = this.sharedService.title;` you will by track changes in your html of the component (with async pipe) in this way `<span>{{ headerTitle$ | async }}</span>`

Was that what you meant? Let me know, if I can explain something.

Comment: Hmmm... I am not able to understand the best solution you are referring to.
But, I will check on that and let you know if I have any doubts on it.